# Why can we break up a capacitor?

Tags: electrostatics

I have a hard time understanding why we are allowed to break up one capacitor into multiple capacitors if the capacitor is filled with different dielectrics. For example, what justifies us to do what was done in this post: [Breaking up a capacitor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/364732/breaking-up-a-capacitor)

Comment: Looking at the link it appears to me to be a thought experiment without any real application.

Comment: @BobD Nonetheless, I still need to figure out why to pass my physics exam

Comment: The first step, breaking up the capacitor into a capacitor "E_1" which is in parallel with a capacitor made up of "E_1" and "E_2" in series (Solution B), is an approximation which assumes that the fringing field region associated with the boundary between "E_1" and "E_2" is relatively small compared to the total size of the capacitor.

Comment: There is a non-insignificant difference between finding out *why* to pass your exam and *how* to pass your exam...